# train dialogflow to recognize phone number

Tags: phone-number, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I would like to extract phone numbers using dialogflow for my chatbot. I was going to use the `@sys.phone-nunmber`, but there is a weird bug in the French version. Even if the system correctly recognizes the number (for instance "06 25 48 79 31") as I can see in the training system when I call the $value associated, I only got the 8 first digits (here it would be "06 25 48 79"). It is quite weird because it is not like the system would have only recognized the first digits. It is only the value that is weird.

Then I tried to create my own @phone-number but the system only recognizes phone numbers I ever showed him. It does not generalize even if I select "Allow automated expansion".

Does someone know how to solve that?

Comment: Can you expand on the bug in the phone number system entity? what issue are you having?

Comment: @matthewayne Well, that is juste the phone number detected (highlighted in training is like 06 09 08 07 06, but the value of the variable when i print it in the answer will be : $value=06 09 08 07. So some number are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no use to train the system anymore because @sys.phone-number has been fixed.